# Attributes missing from geodatabase in QGIS

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, esri-geodatabase

I have been trying to load a gdb file into QGIS, but one of the layers do not show the attributes mentioned in the metadata. The data can be downloaded here. https://pubs.er.usgs.gov/publication/ofr20181088

The layer that doesn't work for me is called "Recent_2013_2017_Mining_Activity_Dataset". The metadata says there should be attributes such as the year of observation, ASM_val (which is the categorisation of mining activities) and others. However, all I am getting is a "count" attribute.

I really don't know what is causing this. Would you have any idea why these other attributes are not displaying in QGIS?

Comment: You checked the availability of the data you are transmitting in this section. Metadata: Metadata (2.60 GB zip) - Text formatted metadata for all data release files

Comment: When I opened that layer, it had these attributes: OBJECTID, FID_1, Id, Count_, Shape_Length, and Shape_Area. If the other attributes you mention are stored in a different table, you could probably join to it based on OBJECTID or FID_1. I don't see any other tables though.

Comment: @csk I don't see other tables either. And the other layers in the same gdb file seems unrelated to this dataset. I have emailed the author of that report to ask about it. Thanks for the comment!